# glossaries - remove left indentation

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package for a mixed glossary with latin and greek letters. In order to get the symbols to the appropriate width, I apply `\glssetwidest{app this width}`. However this produces an indentation on the left, which I'd like to get rid of, because `\glssetwidest{app this width}` seems to specify the width for the parents as well creating this indentation.

MWE:

```
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{alttree}
\glssetwidest{app this width}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latin}{name={Latin letters},
description={}}
\newglossaryentry{greekl}{name={Greek letters},
description={}}

\newglossaryentry{hpt}{name={$\bar{H}^0_{P,T},\bar{H}^0_{P_r,T_r}$},
sort={H0},description={standard partial molal enthalpy at the 
subscripted and reference pressure and temperature},parent=latin}
\newglossaryentry{gamma}{name={$\gamma $},description={activity coefficient},
sort={gamma},parent=greekl}

\begin{document}
\glsaddallunused
\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

I tried `\setlength\LTleft{-5in}`, but this doesn't change anything.

I hope there is someone who can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> I tried `\setlength\LTleft{-5in}`, but this doesn't change anything.

That's a [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) setting so it only applies to the styles that use `longtable`.

With the `alttree` style, `\glssetwidest` has an optional argument that specifies the level. If omitted 0 is assumed so

```
\glssetwidest{app this width}
```

sets the widest entry for level 0 (top level). If the sub-levels don't have a widest entry set then they default to the top level setting.

This means that in your example, "Latin letters" and "Greek Letters" are put in a box that's the same width as `app this width`. This width is used as the offset for the next level down so that the sub-entry name starts below where the parent entry description starts.

Since there's no `\glssetwidest[1]{...}` the sub-entry names are placed in a box that's the same width as the top level setting (the width of `app this width`).

Example that sets different widths for different levels:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\setglossarystyle{alttree}
\glssetwidest{Greek Letters}
\glssetwidest[1]{$\bar{H}^0_{P,T},\bar{H}^0_{P_r,T_r}$}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latin}{name={Latin letters},
description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{greekl}{name={Greek letters},
description={\nopostdesc}}

\newglossaryentry{hpt}{name={$\bar{H}^0_{P,T},\bar{H}^0_{P_r,T_r}$},
sort={H0},description={standard partial molal enthalpy at the 
subscripted and reference pressure and temperature},parent=latin}
\newglossaryentry{gamma}{name={$\gamma $},description={activity coefficient},
sort={gamma},parent=greekl}

\begin{document}
\glsaddallunused
\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

It seems that you don't actually want the sub-entries indented, but that's not the way the tree styles are designed. Since your parent entries don't have a description or number list, you could use a zero-width box for the top-level. (If the parent entries had a description, this would cause the name to overwrite the description.)

This has a slight indent that's caused by the offset between the parent name and parent description:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\setglossarystyle{alttree}
\glssetwidest{}
\glssetwidest[1]{$\bar{H}^0_{P,T},\bar{H}^0_{P_r,T_r}$}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latin}{name={Latin letters},
description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{greekl}{name={Greek letters},
description={\nopostdesc}}

\newglossaryentry{hpt}{name={$\bar{H}^0_{P,T},\bar{H}^0_{P_r,T_r}$},
sort={H0},description={standard partial molal enthalpy at the 
subscripted and reference pressure and temperature},parent=latin}
\newglossaryentry{gamma}{name={$\gamma $},description={activity coefficient},
sort={gamma},parent=greekl}

\begin{document}
\glsaddallunused
\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Given that you're using `nonumberlist` and `\glsaddallunused`, if you're happy to order the entries manually (that is, have them listed according to definition) then you might prefer this method:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sort=none,stylemods,postdot]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrprovidestoragekey{group}{}{\glsgroup}

\setglossarystyle{alttreegroup}

\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{latin}{Latin letters}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greekl}{Greek letters}

\newglossaryentry{hpt}{name={$\bar{H}^0_{P,T},\bar{H}^0_{P_r,T_r}$},
description={standard partial molal enthalpy at the
subscripted and reference pressure and temperature},
group=latin}

\newglossaryentry{gamma}{name={$\gamma $},description={activity coefficient},
group=greekl}

\begin{document}
\glsFindWidestTopLevelName

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

This has switched the ordering around because it's reflecting the order of definition. The order of definition is changed in the modified example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sort=none,stylemods,postdot]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrprovidestoragekey{group}{}{\glsgroup}

\setglossarystyle{alttreegroup}

\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{latin}{Latin letters}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greekl}{Greek letters}

\newglossaryentry{gamma}{name={$\gamma $},description={activity coefficient},
group=greekl}

\newglossaryentry{hpt}{name={$\bar{H}^0_{P,T},\bar{H}^0_{P_r,T_r}$},
description={standard partial molal enthalpy at the
subscripted and reference pressure and temperature},
group=latin}

\begin{document}
\glsFindWidestTopLevelName

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

As long as you don't mind doing the ordering yourself, this method is far more efficient than using `\makenoidxglossaries` and only requires one LaTeX call.